# Groovy -- how would I remove an element from a list based on the content of the element?

Tags: list, groovy, element, removeall

I'm working on a groovy script for Jira -- I'm collecting a list of comments from an issue, and storing the username of the last comment.

Example:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
def commentManager = ComponentAccessor.getCommentManager()
def comments = commentManager.getComments(issue)
if (comments) {
comments.last().authorUser
}
```

Occasionally, I don't want to store the username (if it belongs to a predefined role). Basically, I want to check the comments first, and remove any comments from my list that meet my criteria, then end by calling last().authorUser. Something like:

```
comments.each {
if (it.authorUser.toString().contains(user.toString())) {    
// Here is where I'd want to remove the element from the list**
}
}
comments.last().authorUser  // then store the last element as my most recent comment.
```

Make sense? I am new to Groovy -- so I fully suspect a bunch of head-scratching. Most of the examples I ran into dealt with numeric checking... kinda stumped.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [Collection.removeAll()](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll%28groovy.lang.Closure%29): it modifies the collection by removing elements that are matched by the closure condition passed.

```
comments.removeAll {
    it.authorUser.toString().contains(user.toString())
}
comments.last().authorUser
```

Comment: I forgot to accept this answer -- 2 years ago. I feel like a fool. Sorry Kai -- thanks for the help!

Comment: Here's an updated link to the docs: https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#removeAll(groovy.lang.Closure)

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays one can use Java's `removeIf { it -> it.isNotDog() }`. See some example on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43246613/java-removeif-example).