# Java - removeIf example

Tags: java, lambda

```
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> cityMap = new HashMap<>();
...    
for (ArrayList<Integer> list : cityMap.values()) {
    int size = list.size();
    if (size > 0) {
        list.removeIf(i -> true);
    }
}
```

I don't quite understand what the `removeIf` does in this case. Especially the part (`i -> true`). Thank you for any explanation.

Comment: .values() is a set of lists, and if any of them have items in them, the entire list is removed. `i -> true` just means "always remove".

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-

Comment: In this case, it is a very convoluted and inefficient way of saying `list.clear()`. Likewise, `int size = list.size(); if(size > 0) …` is a verbose way of saying `if(!list.isEmpty()) …`. Since `ArrayList`’s are always mutable and clearing an already empty list has no effect, the test isn’t really necessary. You could use `for (ArrayList<Integer> list : cityMap.values()) list.clear();` instead. Or, if you want to bring in lambda expressions: `cityMap.values().forEach(list -> list.clear());` or a method reference: `cityMap.values().forEach(List::clear);`. All these variants do the same.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 21):

The Javadoc of `removeIf()` states:

> Removes all of the elements of this collection that satisfy the given predicate.

The predicate in your example is always `true` because you map each integer `i` in your list to `true`by the expression: `i -> true`.

I added a simpler example which removes all even integers and keeps all odd integers by the predicate `i % 2 == 0`:

**Ugly setup:**

```
List<List<Integer>> lists = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>() {{
    add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4)));
    add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(2,4,6,8)));
    add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,3,5,7)));
}};
```

**Keep only odd numbers:**

```
for (List<Integer> list : lists) {
    list.removeIf(i -> i % 2 == 0);
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 3]
[]
[1, 3, 5, 7]
```

Answer (score 2):

`removeIf` will go through each element in your list and run the specified predicate (boolean function) on it.  If the predicate returns `true`, it will be removed from the list.  If the predicate returns `false`, it will not.

In your case, every element will result in the predicate returning `true`, thus clearing the list.