# How to remove object if one variable is false in list using java streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I am using java 8
I have a model class like

```
class Student{
    String name;
    List<Subject> subjects1;
    List<Subject> subjects2;
    List<Subject> subjects3;
    // getters & setters
}

class Subject{
    String sub;
    Integer marks;
    boolean status;
    // getters & setters
}
```

`status` may be true or false.
Now if the status is false then I have to remove those objects from the subjects list
How to do it in Streams?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java - removeIf example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43246613/java-removeif-example)

Comment: Is it a list of students or just a list of subjects that you are dealing with here?

Comment: @Turamarth It doesn't answer this question.

Comment: @mang4521 It is not a list of Student. There is one student having list of subject and marks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove objects, you can directly use removeIf method in java 8.

`student.getSubjects().removeIf(subject -> !subject.isStatus());`

Comment: This works fine. Considering there are many lists in Student, Just for examle I have given subjects1, subjects2 etc. In this case can we do it dynamically? In the sence without knowing how many lists of Subject.

Comment: You can use java reflection in that case.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you do it:

```
List<Student> studentsWithTrueStatus = students
  .stream()
  .filter( s -> s.status )
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This is an alternative solution to removing items from the `students`. It does not really remove anything.

Comment: You can just replace the original list with this one. This solves the problem.

Comment: Sure, and **it's not wrong** to do so, I just wanted to point out that this code produces a new list instead of removing items from the source list. Might be of interest for specific readers.

Answer (score 1):

If there are multiple lists of `Subject` in `Student` class, they may be joined using `Stream.of` and then applying `removeIf` in `forEach`:

```java
// Some utility class MyClass
public static void removeSubjects(Student student) {
    Stream.of(student.getSubjects1(), student.getSubjects2(), student.getSubjects3())
        .filter(Objects::nonNull) // filter out null lists if any
        .forEach(subjects -> subjects.removeIf(sub -> !sub.isStatus()));
}
```

---

If there is a list of students, then the reference to the above implemented method may be used for each student:

```java
List<Students> students = Arrays.asList(...); // setup students list

students.forEach(MyClass::removeSubjects);
```

Answer (score 0):

First ensure the list of subjects is not null or empty. Then utilise **removeIf()** method.

```
List<Subject> subjectList = student.getSubjects();

if((null != subjectList) && (subjectList.size() > 0)) {
  subjectList.removeIf(sub -> !(sub.isStatus()));
}
```